# Setting Search Filter on uid AND group membership for Artifactory, LDAP w/AD

Tags: ldap, artifactory

We're evaluating Artifactory to serve as a repo for binaries.  Using OSS.  Got LDAP authentication working (w/ Active Directory).  "Search Filter" looks like...

```
sAMAccountName={0}
```

Want to also filter user based on a group they should also belong to in AD.  Example (output from ldapsearch for a specific user, call from linux)

```
memberOf: CN=xyz.er,OU=Groups/DLs,DC=amd,DC=com
```

Tried various ways of shoehorning this in.  E.g. ...

```
(sAMAccountName={0})&(member=cn=xyz.er)
```

Results in "Error Connecting to LDAP server"
Tried...
    (sAMAccountName={0}&member=cn=xyz.er) 
Resulted in "Failure to authenticate user "

Any ideas...
1) If something like this can be done
2) How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this :

```
(&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberof=CN=xyz.er,OU=Groups/DLs,DC=amd,DC=com))
```